# Eureka Spring cloud - Client instances are not expired

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I created Eureka server and client applications in my local development environment.
My client service instances status is not showing properly even though instances are down.
Below image two services are up and running. Actually, those two services are down more than 30 minutes ago. Any idea to show status as down here?

[image: up and running instances]